# Sorting Citations

Tags: citing

In my thesis, i need to sort my references such that, while everything will be sorted in their turn of appearance, url links will be sorted at the end.

How it is possible using a .bst file?

---

Actually, no. For example i need a bib like;

[1] article
[2] article
[3] url

even if the url is before the articles in the text.

Comment: You mean something like two bibliographies, one for web sources and one for the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this by using categories with biblatex/biber.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

% some bib entries for test purposes:
\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
@ARTICLE{art1,
  TITLE = {Test 1},
  AUTHOR = {Doe, John},
  JOURNAL = {Journal of unreproducible Results},
  YEAR = {2015},
}

@ARTICLE{art2,
  TITLE = {Test 2},
  AUTHOR = {Doe, Jane},
  JOURNAL = {Journal of unreproducible Results},
  YEAR = {2015},
}

@ONLINE{web1,
  TITLE = {Google},
  URL = {www.google.com},
}

@ONLINE{web2,
  TITLE = {Wikipedia},
  URL = {en.wikipedia.org},
}
\end{filecontents}

% sorting = none means same order as the appearance in the document
% biber is the modern backend for biblatex, replacement for bibtex    
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

% create a new category for web sources
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{web}
% add the web entries to the category
\addtocategory{web}{web1,web2}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
See \cite{art1}, \cite{web1}, \cite{art2}, and \cite{web2}!

% one bibliography for the non-web soruces
\printbibliography[notcategory=web, title={Print References}]
% and another one for the websources
\printbibliography[category=web, title={Internet References}]

\end{document}
```

Compile with `latex document.tex`, `biber document.bcf`, `latex document.tex`
where latex is the compiler of your choice.

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: This completely solved my problem. Thank you.